# Calcular días entre dos fechas ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

Busco la forma de calcular en Ionic V2 los días transcurridos entre dos fechas almacenadas en inputs y que muestre el resultado en un modal al hacer clic en el botón calcular.

Esta es la vista en html

```
        <form id="new-form">
            <ion-item id="new-input2">
              <ion-label stacked>
                Fecha inicial
              </ion-label>
              <ion-input type="datetime-local" placeholder="" name="fechaini" [(ngModel)]="fechaini"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item id="new-input3">
              <ion-label stacked>
                Fecha final
              </ion-label>
              <ion-input type="datetime-local" placeholder="" name="fechafin" [(ngModel)]="fechafin"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>                
          </form>
      <button id="button1" ion-button block color="dark" (click)="calcular()">
        Calcular
      </button>
```

Este es el código que tengo en home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

fechaini: any ;
fechafin: any ;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

parseDate(str: string): Date {
    let mdy: String[] = str.split('-');
    return new Date(Number(mdy[0]), Number(mdy[1]) - 1, Number(mdy[2]));
  }

daydiff(first, second): Number {
    return Math.round((second - first) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  }

calcular (){
     let fIni: Date = this.parseDate("1984-1-3");
     let fFin: Date = this.parseDate("1984-1-16");
     let dias: Number = this.daydiff(fIni, fFin);
     console.log("dias:"+dias);
 }

}
```

Comment: Hola YES. Deberias añadir tambien lo que has intentado hasta ahora junto a por qué no te funcionó para poder contextualizar a la gente en tu codigo y tambien los intentos infructuosos. Un saludo

Comment: Hola Alex. Edité la pregunta para añadirle el código que tengo hasta ahora.

Comment: Hola @YESIDDOTNET no es necesario que edites el titulo para poner solucionado, solo recuerda aceptar tu respuesta que publicaste marcandola como respuesta aceptada con el boton en forma de V del lado izquierdo, si no puedes hacerlo en este momento es porque hay un tiempo de gracia para que se pueda hacer ;)

Comment: Gracias, lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente logré resolverlo instalando moment.js

```
npm install --save moment
```

se importa en el controlador y se usa una función para calcular los días, en la vista modifiqué el input por un ion-datetime. El código quedó así:

Formulario en home.html

```
            <form id="new-form">
            <ion-item id="new-input2">
              <ion-label stacked>
                Fecha inicial
              </ion-label>
              <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" placeholder="" name="fechaini" [(ngModel)]="fechaini"></ion-datetime>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item id="new-input3">
              <ion-label stacked>
                Fecha final
              </ion-label>
              <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" placeholder="" name="fechafin" [(ngModel)]="fechafin"></ion-datetime>
            </ion-item>                
          </form>
      <button id="button1" ion-button block color="dark" (click)="calcular()">
        Calcular
      </button>
```

Controlador en home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

fechaini: String;
fechafin: String;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

calcular(){
    let ini = moment(this.fechaini);
    let fin = moment(this.fechafin);
    let diff = fin.diff(ini, 'days');
    console.log(diff);
}
}
```